# Fast file reading

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

If I am right, on Linux (in `C/C++, gcc/g++`), one can read data from a regular file using `read(2)` or `mmap(2)` syscalls.

Two questions. Do `read` syscall use `mmap` internally? When is first faster than the second and vice versa?

Comment: Can you tell us how large your file is, and how many files you have?

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is to try both methods anyway and see which is faster for your particular use. It's hard to say which one *might* be faster because you haven't mentioned any properties of the files you are reading, such as size, whether it contains aligned data, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're reading the file sequentially, my default choice would be to repeatedly `read` into a largish buffer.

If you're accessing small bits of data scattered around a large file, the choice is less clear, but `mmap` could lead to more readable code (since you could code things up as if the file were already in memory). Which would give better performance in this case is hard to tell a priori.

If you're writing performance-critical code, then the only way to ascertain performance is by benchmarking/profiling actual code.

Comment: In fact, `read` absolutely cannot use `mmap`, because it can operate on non-seekable file descriptors (like a pipe, tty, or socket).

Comment: @duskwuff: Thanks for this. I've updated the answer to include your remark.

Comment: It depends on what level of implementation you mean.  I'm pretty sure that under the covers - that is, in the kernel - read frequently does use mmap (or rather, the implementation of the system calls for read and mmap use the same underlying memory mapping machinery) for cases where the fd corresponds to a mappable device.

Comment: @evilotto: Good point, thanks. I've decided to remove that paragraph from the answer since it doesn't add much and is creating unnecessary controversy.

Comment: +1 for "the only way to ascertain performance is by benchmarking/profiling actual code".

Comment: If you wanted to read a file sequentially with `mmap`, you might want to use `madvise` to let the OS know that you'll be sequentially accessing the data.

Answer (score 3):

General rule of thumb:

- if you are reading a file sequentially from start to end you can use read() without performance hit.
- if you are reading a file with random access, mmap() will result in better performance than a comparative seek()/read() combination.

Comment: What @gravitron said. The fastest way is to fstat the file to find its size, then get the thing in one read() operation.

Comment: @PeteWilson: I believe it is faster to mmap the file with the Linux-specific MAP_POPULATE flag, or use posix_madvise.  This essentially maps the file cache into your virtual RAM, saving a copy.

Comment: @PeteWilson I agree with Zan, what you suggest will suffer penalties once the file is of sufficient size to require VM to hold entire file.